# Get custom attributes from an object

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, custom-attributes

When I try to get the custom attributes from an `object` the function returns `null`. Why?

```
class Person
{
    [ColumnName("first_name")]
    string FirstName { get; set; }

    Person()
    {
        FirstName = "not important";
        var attrs = AttributeReader.Read(FirstName);
    }
}

static class AttributeReader
{
    static object[] Read(object column)
    {
        return column.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ColumnNameAttribute), false);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try making FirstName public?

Comment: The code is only a generic example of what I am trying to do.

Comment: Don't you mean to call `var attrs = AttributeReader.Read(Person);`, not `var attrs = AttributeReader.Read(FirstName);` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are passing a `string`, `"not important"` to that method. The `Type` is therefore `typeof(string)`. Which **does not have those attributes**. Further, even `Person` doesn't have that attribute: only the `MemberInfo` (`FirstName`) has them.

There are ways of doing that by passing an `Expression`:

```
public static ColumnNameAttribute[] Read<T>(Expression<Func<T>> func)
{
    var member = func.Body as MemberExpression;
    if(member == null) throw new ArgumentException(
         "Lambda must resolve to a member");
    return (ColumnNameAttribute[])Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(
         member.Member, typeof(ColumnNameAttribute), false);
}
```

with

```
var attrs = AttributeReader.Read(() => FirstName);
```

However! I should advise that I'm not sure that the `Person` constructor is an appropriate place for this. Probably needs caching.

If you don't want to use lambdas, then passing a `Type` and the member-name would work too, i.e.

```
var attrs = AttributeReader.Read(typeof(Person), "FirstName");
```

(and do reflection from there) - or mixing with generics (for no real reason):

```
var attrs = Attribute.Read<Person>("FirstName");
```

Comment: @Segfault my caveat still applies though: I personally wouldn't let that code *anywhere near* an object constructor - it is the wrong place for it.

Comment: Yeah, I was just trying to show what I was trying to do while making the code as clear as possible

Comment: How can I check if a particular attribute is required or not? I am creating an instance of a class as `object obj = Activator.CreateInstance("myModel")` and I need to check if a particular property is required or not: `obj.GetType().GetProperty("prop1").......`.